# Replacing a keyboard shortcut in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shortcuts

I try some hacks to my QGIS UI to make it more keyboard friendly. While I can redefine for example `Esc` and `Ctrl+D`, it doesn't work with `Ctrl+1`. Why?

Attached is my initial plugin (`__init.py__` only).

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QDockWidget, QShortcut
from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeView

def classFactory(iface):
    return KB_Startup(iface)

class KB_Startup:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface

    def initGui(self):
        self.old_conn = []
        self.shortcuts = {}
        self.show_keyboard_focus()
        canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.bind('Esc', canvas.setFocus) # OK!
        self.bind('Ctrl+1', self.focus_layers) # doesn't work :(
        self.bind('Ctrl+D', self.focus_layers) # OK!

    def show_keyboard_focus(self):
        # paint a blue frame around the map canvas, if it has keyboard
        # focus
        canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        self.old_stylesheet = canvas.styleSheet()
        canvas.setStyleSheet(
            'QgsMapCanvas {padding: 2px;} '
            'QgsMapCanvas:focus {background: blue;}')

    def restore_canvas(self):
        canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()
        canvas.setStyleSheet(self.old_stylesheet)
        del self.old_stylesheet

    def focus_layers(self):
        # set keyboard focus on layers panel
        # is it possible to have this in a simple startup.py?
        dock = self.iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Layers')
        dock.setUserVisible(True)
        ltv = dock.findChild(QgsLayerTreeView)
        ltv.setFocus()

    def remove_bindings(self, seq):
        for s in self.iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QShortcut):
            if s.key() == seq:
                # no way to store connections?
                s.disconnect()

        for a in self.iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QAction):
            sc = a.shortcuts()
            for i, s in enumerate(sc):
                if s == seq:
                    sc.pop(i)
                    a.setShortcuts(sc)
                    self.old_conn.append((a, i, seq))
                break

    def bind(self, strseq, slot):
        seq = QKeySequence(strseq)
        self.remove_bindings(seq)
        sc = QShortcut(seq, self.iface.mainWindow())
        sc.setContext(Qt.ShortcutContext.ApplicationShortcut)
        sc.activated.connect(slot)
        self.shortcuts[seq] = sc

    def restore_bindings(self):
        for s in self.shortcuts.values():
            s.disconnect()
        # no way to restore QShortcut connections?

        for a, i, seq in self.old_conn:
            sc = a.shortcuts()
            sc.insert(i, seq)
            a.setShortcuts(sc)

    def unload(self):
        self.restore_canvas()
        self.restore_bindings()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `remove_bindings()` I had to replace `s.disconnect` with `s.setEnabled(False)`. And now it looks like I don't need to create a plugin, but I can have it as `startup.py` like this:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QDockWidget, QShortcut
from qgis.gui import QgsLayerTreeView
from qgis.utils import iface

def show_keyboard_focus(canvas):
    # paint a blue frame around the map canvas, if it has keyboard
    # focus
    canvas.setStyleSheet(
        'QgsMapCanvas {padding: 2px;} '
        'QgsMapCanvas:focus {background: blue;}')

def focus_layers():
    # set keyboard focus on layers panel
    dock = iface.mainWindow().findChild(QDockWidget, 'Layers')
    dock.setUserVisible(True)
    ltv = dock.findChild(QgsLayerTreeView)
    ltv.setFocus()

def remove_bindings(seq):
    for s in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QShortcut):
        if s.key() == seq:
            s.setEnabled(False)

    for a in iface.mainWindow().findChildren(QAction):
        sc = a.shortcuts()
        for i, s in enumerate(sc):
            if s == seq:
                sc.pop(i)
                a.setShortcuts(sc)
            break

def bind(strseq, slot):
    seq = QKeySequence(strseq)
    remove_bindings(seq)
    sc = QShortcut(seq, iface.mainWindow())
    sc.setContext(Qt.ShortcutContext.ApplicationShortcut)
    sc.activated.connect(slot)

canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
show_keyboard_focus(canvas)
bind('Esc', canvas.setFocus)
bind('Ctrl+1', focus_layers)
```

New questions are arising: Should I better create QAction instead of QShortcut? Do I have to consider the shortcut manager or QSettings?